# Custom Test for Hash Table Equality in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, hashtable, equality

A simple test for equality of two hash tables is `(equalp ht1 ht2)`, which tests for (1) same :test argument, (2) same hash-table-count, (3) same keys and values, and (4) equalp values. However, I need a faster comparison, since this simple test is consuming about 40% of program run time (according to statistical profiling in sbcl). So it looks like (1) and (4) and part of (3) are unnecessary. The following is an attempt at reducing the run time (includes a suggested improvement from coredump):

```
(defun hash-table-equal-keys (ht1 ht2)
  "Determines if all the keys of two hash tables are the same."
  (and (= (hash-table-count ht1) (hash-table-count ht2))
       (loop for key1 being the hash-keys of ht1
           always (gethash key1 ht2))))
```

However, the effect on run time is negligible.

The basic requirement involves only the presence/absence of keys in the table, which is intensely accessed and updated at runtime. The keys are also computed at runtime based on some number of variables--eg, sym1, sym2, ...--whose values are taken from a fixed set of symbols. Currently I'm setting this up with a macro, one aspect of which builds hash table access/update using `(gethash (list sym1 sym2 ...) ht)`. But this requires an inefficient `#'equal` hash table, in addition to the consing and list building for the key.

A more efficient approach might have the macro build an access like `(gethash (intern (concatenate 'string (symbol-name sym1) (symbol-name sym2) ...)) ht)`, which basically substitutes string concatenation for list building. It also allows an `#'eq` hash table. Are there any issues related to this approach?

Update: Changing the program to use an #'eq hash table with concatenate results in much worse performance. Evidently translating keys from lists to symbols involves too much overhead.

Comment: To clarify: you are using the hash-table as a set?

Comment: `when ... do ... finally`  can be replaced by `always (gethash key1 ht2)`

Comment: Can you encode your keys so that they can be compared with EQL instead?

Comment: @Svante Yes, as a set of lists of symbols.

Comment: @coredump Would it make sense to try concatenating each list of symbols into a string as a key? I'm assuming the hash-table :test #'equal would then translate internally into #'string=, which could be more efficient than #'equal for lists?

Comment: @davypough If you have symbols, they can be compared by identity (EQ) which is more efficient than string comparison. EQUAL on a list of symbols might be already good enough. I was more thinking about integers: if your set of possible symbols is fixed, each could be associated with a bit mask (you would logior all the symbols in a list to get a number). But maybe this is not a good idea for your problem. Could you describe a little more what you need to do?

Comment: @coredump It looks like I might be able to apply your idea by (1) first assigning each symbol an integer--eg, sym1->int1, there are usually under 100 but the input symbols vary, (2) instead of computing lookups like (gethash (list sym2 sym8 sym3) ht), do (gethash (op (list int2 int8 int3)) ht), where op uniquely combines the integers into another integer as key, and (3) translating the final program output back into symbols. (cont'd)

Comment: @coredump (cont'd) You mentioned logior, but this would not generate unique integers for different permutations of the integer list. Is there an efficient way for op to concatenate all the integer digits (or bits) into a bigger integer (or bit vector)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous clarification changed to more of an answer:

As suggested previously, first create a hash table associating each possible symbol with an integer (or fixnum). Since there are less than 100 symbols, the numbers could range from 1 up to 99. Then at runtime, convert a given sequence of symbols to their respective integers: eg, (sym1 sym2 sym3) -> (16 88 3). These can be combined into a larger integer by multiplying the first by 1, the second by 100, and the third by 100x100=10,000, and so on if more integers, summing as you go. The combination is efficient, since it is based on integer arithmetic. The resulting integer should be unique for any permutation of input integers, and can be used in an eql hash table to access the original symbol sequence.

Comment: This does not look like an answer.  Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, you have sets of lists of symbols.  Comparing these (which also will happen in a hashtable lookup) can be expensive, if the keys that you look up are hashed each time.

Maybe you can replace the hash-table with a custom structure that has more overhead at creation time, but compares much faster: at creation, you bring the contents into a canonical order (sort them), then hash them (you most likely need a *good* hash function; `sxhash` is often rather optimized for speed than collision resistance).  Comparison then becomes hash (integer) equality.

Comment: Are you thinking of a precomputed reference hash table which would contain every possible sequence of symbols keyed by an integer from 1 to (all combinations of n symbols with replacement)? But then it seems I still need to efficiently compute that access integer at runtime in order to determine presence/absence in the table (as mentioned in comment to coredump above). Sorry if I'm missing your suggestion.

Comment: No, I'm thinking of putting your hash-table into a struct that also holds a hash of the entire thing, computed at key creation time.  Comparing hash-tables is then comparing the already computed hashes.  This is a tradeoff where creating the hash-tables is slower, but comparison faster.  I don't know if it fits your application, i. e., whether the tables are (best case) immutable or (maybe ok) updated less frequently than compared.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I would like to better understand your suggestion (given hash keys are created on the fly from symbols during runtime). And, yes, I estimate hash table access is about 10 times more frequent than update.

Answer (score 0):

The first test condition `(= (hash-table-count ht1) (hash-table-count ht2))` traverses both ht1 and then ht2.

Comment: Hash-table-count is most likely implemented as an internal counter. The standard hints at this. Granted, there is technically no obligation to implement it efficiently, but I don't think there is an implementation where there is traversal involved (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/f_hash_1.htm)